# Pass URL to iframe in WordPress Block

Tags: functions, block-editor, iframe

I have a WordPress site with an `iframe` that displays custom content from an external site.

Here is my `iframe` code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.targetsite.com/UNIQUECODE" width="800" height="800">
```

I want the "UNIQUECODE" in the iframe to populate based on the browser URL (my site is example.com):

```
http://www.example.com/iframepage?UNIQUECODE
```

Is this possible with the WordPress block editor and/or with an update to functions.php?

Comment: Yes of course. How are you generating the iframe mark-up? Just typing the HTML into a block, from PHP in a template, something else?

Comment: Just typing it into a block right now...